# Nested pointer to struct containing pointer to containing struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, unions, double-pointer

First, I have a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
    union expr value;
}lval;
```

and union which is defined as below to save room:

```
union expr{
    long num;
    char* err;
    char* sym;
    sexpr* sexpr1;
};
```

and in the `sexpr*` is

```
typedef struct {
    int count;
    struct lval** cell;
}sexpr;
```

I try to use it as below,

```
void lval_del(lval* v){
     lval_del(v->value.sexpr1->cell[i]); 
}
```

but my compiler gave me a warning:

> Parameter type mismatch: Incompatible 
>    pointer types 'lval *' and 'struct anonymous::lval *'.

When I try code like below

```
lval* lval_add(lval* v,lval* x) {
    v->value.sexpr1->cell = realloc(v->value.sexpr1->cell, sizeof(lval*)*v->value.sexpr1->count);
    v->value.sexpr1->cell[v->value.sexpr1->count-1]=x;
    return v;
}
```

I get the same warning.

I ignored the warning and compiled it successfully, but when I run it, it crashes. I think it's the problem causing the warning. How can I solve it?

Edit: the full code as I compiled it is below:

```
typedef struct {
   int count;
   struct lval** cell;
}sexpr;

union expr{
    long num;
    char* err;
    char* sym;
    sexpr* sexpr1;
};

typedef struct {
    int type;
    union expr value;
}lval;

void lval_del(lval* v){
    switch (v->type) {
        case LVAL_NUM:
            break;
        case LVAL_ERR:
            free(v->value.err);
            break;
        case LVAL_SYM:
            free(v->value.sym);
            break;
        case LVAL_SEXPR:
            for (int i=0;i<v->value.sexpr1->count;i++){
                lval_del(v->value.sexpr1->cell[i]);
            }
            free(v->value.sexpr1->cell);
        default:break;
    }
}

lval* lval_add(lval* v,lval* x) {
    v->value.sexpr1->count ++;
    v->value.sexpr1->cell = realloc(v->value.sexpr1->cell,sizeof(lval*)*v->value.sexpr1->count);
    v->value.sexpr1->cell[v->value.sexpr1->count-1]=x;
    return v;
}
```

edit:  7.24
I killed the warning by defining them in this order. A complex struct is a nightmare for me, I gave up trying to deal with the pointer problem. Below is my new code, still with the bad pointer.

```
struct init_lval;
struct init_sexpr;
typedef struct init_sexpr sexpr;
union expr{
    long num;
    char* err;
    char* sym;
    sexpr* sexpr1;
};
typedef struct init_lval lval;

struct init_lval
{
    int type;
    union expr value;
};

struct init_sexpr{
   int count;
   lval** cell;
};
lval* lval_add(lval* v, lval* x) {
    v->value.sexpr1->count ++;
    v->value.sexpr1->cell = realloc(v->value.sexpr1->cell,sizeof(lval*)*v->value.sexpr1->count);
    v->value.sexpr1->cell[v->value.sexpr1->count-1]=x;
    return v;
}
void lval_del(lval* v){
    switch (v->type) {
        case LVAL_NUM:
            break;
        case LVAL_ERR:
            free(v->value.err);
            break;
        case LVAL_SYM:
            free(v->value.sym);
            break;
        case LVAL_SEXPR:
            for (int i=0;i<v->value.sexpr1->count;i++){
                lval_del(v->value.sexpr1->cell[i]);
            }
            free(v->value.sexpr1->cell);
            free(v->value.sexpr1);
        default:break;
    }
    free(v);
}
```

Comment: `I ignored the warning and complied it successfully.`..root of all problems.

Comment: Warnings apart is `lval_del` really recursive? If it is, when do you think the recursion should stop during run time?

Comment: Did you forget to pre declare `struct lval;`?

Comment: The two struct is def recursively, but I try your method as add the struct lval; before sexpr, then edit below lval* to struct lval*, it still get a crash. May I dont get your real mean, hope you can give your code out.

Comment: What data structure are you trying to implement with this code? Does `cell` really need to be a `lval **`?

Comment: when defining a union or a struct, always include a 'tagname' so the data can be properly referenced (and properly displayed via a debugger

Answer (score 1):

`struct lval** cell;` is invalid, you do not have a `struct lval`, you `typedef`ed an anonymous struct to `lval`.

Change it to `lval **cell;`

You also do not increment `v->value.sexpr1->count` in your `add` function, so it will always write to the same position.

Comment: It's not ok.After changed, complier will not revolve the lval befor **cell.

Comment: Sorry,I dont show my full code to  stand out problem.I  increment my count correctly.

Comment: As I see, it is a type error.If you think differ, I can post my full code.

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is with realloc. You are trying to realloc the memory which is never malloced. In addition you need to allocate memory to `sexpr1` before using it in the expressions like `v->value.sexpr1->cell`

Try this:

```
lval* lval_add(lval* v,lval* x) {
    v->value.sexpr1->count ++;
    if(v->value.sexpr1->cell == NULL) {
        v->value.sexpr1->cell = malloc(sizeof(lval*)*v->value.sexpr1->count);
    } else {
        v->value.sexpr1->cell = realloc(v->value.sexpr1->cell,sizeof(lval*)*v->value.sexpr1->count);
    }
    v->value.sexpr1->cell[v->value.sexpr1->count-1]= (struct lval*)x;
    return v;
}
```

And initialise the `lval` which is being passed to `lval_add`, like this:

```
lval *z = malloc(sizeof(lval));
z->value.sexpr1 = malloc(sizeof(sexpr));
z->value.sexpr1->cell= NULL;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `realloc(NULL,size);` is the same as `malloc(size);`.

Comment: Oh yeah... We can use that either. But the pointer has to be really NULL in that case. See if you have properly initialised in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter type mismatch: Incompatible pointer types 'lval *' and 'struct anonymous::lval *'.

The above warning is because you have an anonymous struct. try:

```
typedef struct lval {
    int type;
    union expr value;
};
```

This should resolve this warning at least.

Comment: I try it but not work.May I also need to change the def order of these struct/union In your way?